# Regex to match and clean quotes in python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, web-scraping

I have a bunch of quotes scraped from Goodreads stored in a `bs4.element.ResultSet`, with each element of type `bs4.element.Tag`. I'm trying to use regex with the re module in python 3.6.3 to clean the quotes and get just the text. When I iterate and print using `[print(q.text) for q in quotes]` some quotes look like this

> “Don't cry because it's over, smile because it happened.”
>
> ―

while others look like this:

> “If you want to know what a man's like, take a good look at how he
>   treats his inferiors, not his equals.”
>
> ―
>
> ,

Each also has some extra blank lines at the end. My thought was I could iterate through `quotes` and call `re.match` on each quote as follows:

```
cleaned_quotes = []    
for q in quote:
    match = re.match(r'“[A-Z].+$”', str(q))
    cleaned_quotes.append(match.group())
```

I'm guessing my regex pattern didn't match anything because I'm getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Not surprisingly, printing the list gives me a list of `None` objects. Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: why not simply strip trailing whitespace using `q.strip()`?

Comment: Two reasons: First, I'm still learning and wanted to practice using regex. Second, I found myself having to use q.strip() and q.replace('–', '') to get rid of the hyphens and was hoping regex would allow me to get just the quote text in one line.

Comment: Well, getting rid of a '-' and trailing whitespace seems easier than a regex for a random sentence...

Comment: Couldn't I just match the quotation marks at the start and end of each quote and be done with it? It seems like it should be pretty quick in theory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you requested this for learning purpose, here's the regex answer:

```
(?<=“)[\s\s]+?(?=”)
```

Explanation:

We use a [positive lookbehind to and lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to mark the beginning and end of the pattern and remove the quotes from result at the same time.
Inside of the quotes we lazy match anything with the `.+?`

[Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1brRrK/2/)

Sample Code:

```
import re
regex = r"(?<=“)[\s\S]+?(?=”)"
cleaned_quotes = []    
for q in quote:
    m = re.search(regex, str(q))
    if m:
        cleaned_quotes.append(m.group())
```

Arguably, we do not need any regex flags. Add the `g`|gloabal flag for multiple matches. And `m`|multiline to process matches line by line (in such a scenario could be required to use `[\s\S]` instead of the dot to get line spanning results.)
This will also change the behavior of the positional [anchors](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` and `$`, to match the end of the line instead of the string. Therefore, adding these positional anchors in-between is just wrong.

One more thing, I use `re.search()` since `re.match()` matches only from the beginning of the string. A common gotcha. See the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#search-vs-match).

Comment: Impressive, +1 for the lookahead/lookbehind

Comment: This worked perfectly and was very educational. Thanks! And I see why I should have been matching [\s\S]+ instead of just .+

Comment: @wp78de accepted. I have less than 15 reputation so I can't upvote yet haha.

Comment: @PrratekRamchandani fixed :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in your expression `r'“[A-Z].+$”'` end of line `$` is defined before `"`, which is logically not possible.
To use `$` in regexi for multiline strings, you should also specify `re.MULTILINE` flag.

Second - `re.match` expects to match the whole value, not find part of string that matches regular expression.
Meaning `re.search` should do what you initially expected to accomplish.

So the resulting regex could be:
`re.search(r'"[A-Z].+"$', str(q), re.MULTILINE)`

Comment: This will not work in the presence of trailing whitespace or the '-' at the end of the quote.